# How to query mongodb from a search form using node and express

Tags: node.js, express, node-mongodb-native

I want to make an HTML form to query MongoDB.  How can I write the logic to ignore blank fields?  For example, I have two search parameters.  If the lastname field is blank, how would I write the query to ignore that field?

```
router.post('/auth/search', auth, function(req,res){
    var db = req.db;
    console.log(req.body);
    db.users.find({ 'firstname': req.body.firstname,
                    'lastname' :req.body.lastname  // if this field is blank in the form how can I ignore it?

    }, function(err, docs){
        if (err) return err;
        console.log(docs);
        res.send(docs);
    });
});
```

Appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add properties to your query only if they’re truthy:

```
var query = {};

if (req.body.firstname) {
    query.firstname = req.body.firstname;
}

if (req.body.lastname) {
    query.lastname = req.body.lastname;
}

db.users.find(query, function (err, docs) {
    // …
});
```

Answer (score -2):

By making search object dynamically.

```
router.post('/auth/search', auth, function(req,res){
    var db = req.db;
    console.log(req.body);
    var obj = {}
    if(req.body.firstname) {
        obj['firstname'] = req.body.firstname;
    }
    if(req.body.lastname) {
        obj['lastname'] = req.body.lastname;
    }

    db.users.find(obj, function(err, docs){
        if (err) return err;
        console.log(docs);
        res.send(docs);
    });
});
```

Comment: `curl -d '$where=function () { while (true); }'` says “don’t do that”.

Comment: @HarpreetSingh, it's a matter of whitelisting/sanitizing your inputs. You don't want to openly trust any parameter that's being sent from the end user.

Comment: Oh yes, sure it would be a big mistake. Though I know that but slipped from mind this time. Now it will be remembered forever. Thanks :)